# How do I move some folders on my LOCAL machine without it making changes in the repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

First off, I'm a total neophyte on this stuff, and I'm not a programmer. I'm only using SVN because the project manager insists on it. I'm using Win7 and TortoiseSVN.

I want the path on my local machine to be exactly the same as on the server (i.e., the repository). On the repository it's like this:

**../ProjectName/Week1/ProjectFiles**

When I checked them out I must have made a mistake, because the "ProjectFiles" folder ended up a level back. So on my local machine it's like this:

**..\ProjectName\ProjectFiles**

The **..\ProjectName\Week1** folder is there on my local machine. Without SVN I'd just drag the **ProjectFile**s folder and drop it in there. But everything I read says to not do that, and any moving I do will result in a similar move on the server once I check the files in or try to update.

I don't want to re-download the files because it's a huge project with 100s of MBs of files. I just want to move the folder so the paths are the same in both locations.

*The question:*

How can I move the **ProjectFiles** folder into the **Week1** folder without there being any changes on the server?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not exactly sure why the folder ended in the wrong parent folder, but what happens if you do a `revert` (should be in the context menu of the topmost folder that is checked out, i.e. shows a Tortoise state icon)? That will revert everything to the state on the server, without downloading everything. Only use this if you didn't make any relevant changes to the files inside the folder that you don't want to loose!

Answer (score 1):

The things you've read are correct, any changes to the checkout version are tracked and will be propagated to the server on commit.

Your best bet is to simply delete everything you've downloaded and checkout again.

If you've made changes to files that you want to save, then checkout a new working copy, move the files you've updated to the correct place in the new checkout, verify that all your changes are in the right place, then delete the old checkout (so you don't accidentally commit those changes) and continue working in the new checkout.

Comment: Thanks James. What I don't understand is how the move would be reflected on the repository. In this case the repository is structured like /1/2/3 and my local is like /1/3. So if I move the local from /1/3 to /1/2/3, how will that move manifest on the respository? (Because on the repository it's SUPPOSED to be /1/2/3!)

Comment: you'd move the files in the 1/3 structure to where they're supposed to be in the 1/2/3 structure.  That would, to subversion, simply look like 1/2/3/a.src was modified (assuming you moved 1/3/a.src to 1/2/3/a.src).